# Why does Google push notification with invalid token succeeds

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm sending push notifications to android device using GCM service and the token that is send by device. Everything is working well.
Now if I change the device token and add an arbitrary string to the **start of the token** GCM still sends the notification. But if I add something to end of the token Google responds with error!
Here is a successful token:

> testen0xLucMNBo:APA91bEkZjKCUVT30O7J9OMZoUWmjdRb3jIFfRBwp62hgK3JEbJ20MlPvpKWXkQj8YMKuVHOyhNfRiG5Op1lh68iT_D_-81JhKXhLVYi1KrWx1Qu7L6WSnm9-oOhFHdKsmjo-qm_9Ana

Notice the `test` in the beginning of token. That's what I added.

And this is what google replies.

> {"multicast_id":8394350681994886128,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1479811125743676%3595830d66d6cf16"}]}

Is it a normal behavior? Is there such a behavior specified in Google docs anywhere?

Comment: The actual token is the string after :APA.. But im not sure what is the first part

Comment: Just to make it clear, the actual token is the *whole* String itself, not just the part after `:APA`. This is an unexpected behavior. I managed to replicate it myself. I suggest reaching out to [GCM Support](https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support) (or [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) if you're actually using FCM) to further look into this.

Comment: @AL. I tested what X3Btel said and it's true. Whatever you place before APA doesn't break the token what you send later will. GCM should clarify this in their documentation

Comment: That is what I'm exactly saying as the *unexpected behavior*. The Registration token returned should not be modified in any way (add/remove a character), hence it should return an [InvalidRegistration](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes). Did you reach out to the Support group?

Comment: @AL. It's unfortunate that since I live in Iran I can't use google support.

Comment: Oww. I didn't know that there was a restriction like that when reaching out to the support teams (was fairly sure there wasn't any). Can you cross-post this in the [android-gcm Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/android-gcm) too? (nake sure to indicate that you are cross-posting from Stack Overflow) There might be someone there who can shed some light on this. :)